# Craft 3 CMS Poll Plugin

Tags: craft3, plugins

Are there any poll plugins available for Craft 3?
As in have radio buttons, show % results for number of people that have voted for the different options after submission.

Thanks

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, that's why I'm building one at the moment :)
Could you elaborate on your requirements, then maybe I could try to build 'm into my plugin.

Comment: Basically, all I need is the ability to create a radio button list of options with a question above. Then once the person has chosen an answer and clicked submit they are given view of the % amount of submitted results for each option. But there needs to be the ability to add multiple polls that are active at a single time. Once the poll has expired, it just shows the % results for each answer.

Comment: any update on this? I am also looking for a poll plugin, have been using it for expression engine for years, but there's no similar for Craft 3